# AppsFlyer integration enable/disable tracking in android not working as expected?

Tags: android, appsflyer

I have integrated AppsFlyer in my app. But not able to activate and deactivate tracking as per my requirement. Eg In facebook we use:
to activate:

```
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

and to deactivate:

```
AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
```

In AppsFlyer tutorial, it is given how to enable or disable tracking:

```
 AppsFlyerLib.setDeviceTrackingDisabled(true);


 @Override
 public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 AppsFlyerLib.onActivityResume(this);
 }
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
 super.onPause();
 AppsFlyerLib.onActivityPause(this); 
 }
```

But in my code, its not taking this code.

```
 AppsFlyerLib.setDeviceTrackingDisabled
```

dependency using :

```
 compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.3.8@aar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Opt-out (aka COPPA) is available from 4.7.0 (you use `4.3.8`). The latest Android version see [HERE](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android).

Once you set `AppsFlyerLib.setDeviceTrackingDisabled(true);` - the flag `deviceTrackingDisabled:true` will be sent to AppsFlyer and data will not be stored.

Comment: But problem if we want to disable any sending requests to the server, how can we do it? And if method called like setDeviceTrackingDisabled, then we expected that any tracking activity should be disabled. Seems that disabling logic should be handled by client, not on the server side, otherwise we always send some info to the server. Maybe we need addtional method which disable any tracking activity on client side

Comment: @user1221256 not at all. SDK is pretty simple and we do not block traffic on SDK side. When server receives `deviceTrackingDisabled:true`, it doesn't forward some fields like device name and so on. This is done by policy agreement. So no worries. You can always contact customer support: `support@appsflyer.com` and they will answer on all your questions